# shortening python "if" statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been constantly coding in Python using this inefficient style

```
    checkbox = self.request.get(u'checkbox') # get data from a web form
    if checkbox == u'yes':
        someclass.enabled = True
    else:
        someclass.enabled = False
```

how do I shorten this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
someclass.enabled = self.request.get(u'checkbox') == u'yes'
```

Comment: To upvoters: this answer is correct - but why to upvote it throughthe roof? This makes S.O. a system of "answer fast to get more points". The answers bellow are as good as this, and it is not fair that the ability to type this in a few seconds less than other people would be valued so much. (John Mee: nothing personal - your answer is good - but even going this right to the point,a nd that fast, a "4" would be a nice final score for such an answer)

Comment: @jsbueno: This is a kind of game, isn't it? I do not think it hurts anyone. I would rather ask the ben0 to change the military view at the World ;)

Comment: pepr: It is a kind of game, but also a system where one expects the high ranked answers to be the most usefull or insightfull. And it is up to us, the users, to try to achieve fairness in this sense. (I for one did upvote the equivalent answers on this thread)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without an `if` statement:

`someclass.enabled = (checkbox == u'yes')`

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the value to the outcome of the statement:

```
checkbox = self.request.get(u'checkbox') # get data from a web form
someclass.enabled = checkbox == u'yes'
```

Answer (score 2):

As `checkbox == u'yes'` returns a boolean value you can simply assign this result to the variable directly.

```
someclass.enabled = (checkbox == u'yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could split it into a different function:

```
def getCheckboxValue(name):
    return (self.request.get(name) == u'yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python eval the statement and return the output to the statement. So you can use the assign variable in right side.

like

`variable = eval_statment`

so your example will be

```
someclass.enabled = self.request.get(u'checkbox') == u'yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear if you used booleans in your example because they were inherent to your problem or because they were a convenient example.  If you want to assign to variables more complicated types than booleans, you may also want to check out Python's ternary operator (if you're using version 2.5 or greater):

```
someclass.int_val = 1 if checkbox == u'yes' else 2
```

which translates to

```
if checkbox == u'yes':
    someclass.int_val = 1
else
    someclass.int_val = 2
```

For boolean variables, I'd recommend using Yuushi's solution, but for completeness, this is what it would look like:

```
someclass.enabled = True if checkbox == u'yes' else False
```

It's about the same amount of typing, but saves some vertical space, which can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need more than a boolean value, you should consider using the dispatch pattern:

```
targets = {
  'yes': do_yes,
  'no': do_no,
  'maybe': do_maybe,
}

targets[self.request.get(u'tricheckbox')]()

# where do_yes, do_no, and do_maybe are the functions to call for each state.
```

Answer (score -1):

As pointed-out in another answer you could use dispatch table to do different things based on a value. However using a dictionary's `get()` method rather than \performing a direct lookup would allow you to also easily handle cases where nothing matches. Since the mapping won't be used again it can be temporary and anonymous.

This approach is very generic and can expanded as necessary, but usually requires extra functions to be written. Because of the latter, for very simple cases like your example, one of the other answers would probably require the least effort.

```
def do_yes(): print 'do_yes'
def do_no(): print 'do_no'
def do_maybe(): print 'do_maybe'
def no_match(): print 'no_match'

{
  u'yes': do_yes,
  u'no': do_no,
  u'maybe': do_maybe,
}.get(self.request.get(u'checkbox'), no_match) ()
```